# Can I pass an OBJECT to an external executable in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, object, parameters, executable

We are in the process of building a new Ledger program (VB.NET over SQL Server), and in the phase of decision... "MDI or Multiple executable programs?"

The advantage of the multiple executable programs (driven by a common menu) is the maintainability of the code, and the ease of personalization for particular customers.

The question, though, is: Can I pass a parameter when launching a new process, that is NOT a string or an Integer?
Better said: Can  pass an object (Be it a collection, a datatable or whatever the application requires) when I shell a new instance of an executable?

Anyone has an idea about it? (And, maybe, a small piece of code... :-)))

thank you!

Comment: Serializing an xml or json document would be an option.  And, no to providing code, lots of examples online, and SO isn't a code writing service.  And, this isn't part of your question, but creating "multiple executable programs" does not automatically mean code is more maintainable or can be easily customized. An MDI design, or creating interfaces via separate dll assemblies, or other design patterns, can be as valid a way to create maintainable and customizable code. Depends on how you go about your chosen design.

Comment: Oh, I perfectly understand that SO isn't a code writing service, for heaven's sake!
I wondered if anyone already had something like that.

Comment: And yes, I was pushing hard towards MDI, but that way isn't very well accepted by upper management.
So, I am forced to have a main "Menu" that calls separate executables, instead of a (cleaner) MDI main form.
The oroblem is that I don't want to reload all the needed resources every time I launch a program. But... How can I share them? (VB.NET)

Comment: Instead of MDI, try Multiple *Window* Interface. One executable which opens windows as you need them. What you are proposing would be very inefficient. Imagine two apps share many assembly references, then you would need to load the same assemblies into memory once for each app instance. Better to come up with a different architecture

Comment: @djv You tell me... I'll look into MWI, ok. Thank you for supporting MDI, though.
:-(

Comment: @PieroGiorgi the main application at my workplace uses MDI and it is highly customizable. But your issue is not really MDI vs MWI (I don't know if that's a real thing or if we just made it up), it's how you provide configuration. You should really investigate factory patterns for initializing different windows based on configuration. This can be done with MDI or not, and the difference is only a few lines of code so it is almost inconsequential.

Comment: @djv True that. Problem is that I carry around a rather big class with a gazillion of parameters, plus many application.settings thingys.
So, basically, the question is: Can I pass a CLASS to an EXE, instead of a string?

Comment: @djv And Yes, we made up MWI, unless you were talking about "Micro Wave IGNITION" :-D

Comment: @PieroGiorgi the first comment here about serializing your object in xml might be your best bet

Comment: @PieroGiorgi actually a database might be a better route

Comment: You could also host a WCF service in your exe, and after launching the exe, communicate with it through the WCF service for exchanging data and passing commands, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I pass an OBJECT to an external executable in VB.net?

No. Whatever argument you pass to an executable will always be collected as a string within that executable.

Note that the `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` method returns a `String` array.

Comment: Ok. This is definitive.
We'll find a way around.

Thank you

Comment: Then I can serialize the object in an XML string and pass it... Maybe.

Comment: @PieroGiorgi ~ If your XML contains spaces it'll break your application. Arguments are space-delimited. It's tempting to mitigate this by wrapping the string in quotes, but the XML likely will contain quotes of its own. The same is true with JSON. One possible solution is to persist the XML/JSON to disk and send the filename (wrapped in quotes, just in case).

Comment: Hmmmmmyes, but I can Base64 the whole thing, correct?

Comment: @PieroGiorgi ~ Ah yes, good idea. As long as your argument falls within [these limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation). But I must admit I'm scratching my head a bit over your proposed design. It strikes me as tedious to build and difficult to maintain. You might be headed into a world of pain. A separate executable for each component of the application? Ouch. Could you provide some more background on this choice?

Comment: Ah, yes, you are VERY correct. Really painful, from a development point of view.
THe reasoning behind it is that the software that we make is highly customized between customers, that can very often have a different version of the same form, due to their necessities.
This would force the maintenance of (n) versions of the whole procedure, instead of only the involved forms.
Secondly, the company gives me currency in exchange of my time; currency that I can use for food, COFFEE, and shelter (Which are important), so... Just go with the flow.

Comment: I don't have all the details, naturally, but at first glance this seems a clear case for MEF.

Comment: Hm... MEF?. Can you define? (I suppose it can be fun)